# Which exception should I throw if the requested entity does not exist in Db?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception

Imagine a method, that attempts to retrieve an entity which SHOULD exist in the Db in terms of Business Logic (for a specific case).

When I try to retrieve it from the Db via my Repository and if I get back `null`, which exception I should throw?  (I was thinking `ObjectNotFoundException`)

Comment: If accessing using a unique ID - KeyNotFoundException

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One could argue whether an exception is needed at all; why not return an empty collection or null?

The kind of Exception you should use depends on the way you are using exceptions in the application.

The first thing you might consider is whether or not it is a functional error (should the user correct something) or a technical error (did the developers make a mistake).

Another thing you should consider is what is natural for the caller of the method.

Comment: +1 for `null` rather than an exception

Comment: Why to throw an exception? Well, it is because from the business logic perspective this record should exist because it represents a DEFAULT value for a specific case. So if it does not exist, the (server-side) method cannot proceed -even though the request (which is coming from a WCF service).

Comment: From a business perspective you never need an exception. From your description it feels like a technical error that shouldn't occur. In that case you can pick any name that is meaningful to the caller. By the way, do not expose an exception from WCF but a SOAP fault instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "pick any name that is meaningful to the caller. " You mean pick any meaningful Exception type?

Comment: Yes, you can pick an existing one but you could create a custom exception as well. THe important thing is that the caller understands what is going on and perhaps how to solve it when this exception occurs.

Comment: If you really must throw an exception then maybe use the `ObjectNotFoundException` here, [ObjectNotFoundException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objectnotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

A more preferred route might be to investigate `Maybe<T>` monads and return a `Maybe<YourEntity>` instead? http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/monads-in-c-5-maybe.html

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't throw an exception for this sort of scenario, just handle the `null` return value instead. It's not really a good idea to start using exceptions to control application flow.

If the entity should *definitely* be there then you could handle the `null` value in the Business Layer and throw a custom domain exception e.g. `EntityNotFoundException`, however, I wouldn't put that sort of logic at repository level.

Comment: Having to check for `nulls` does not lead to over clean code, as a method which returns a `null` if not found does not express intent clearly. Maybe consider returning a `Maybe<T>` which _clearly_ expresses that either **one** or **zero** of the type to be returned _has_ been returned.

Comment: Null doesn't tell you anything either when you try to test this method.

Comment: Throwing exceptions is nice as you can just handle them on the most outer layer, and you don't have many if result == null statement in your code.